# How to load socket.io script in HTML only when user click button?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I have a socket-io script on my client side that just do the simple task of connecting to a server. So far , so good.

What I am trying to do is to load the javascript script containing socket.io  ONLY when a button is clicked by the user and not when the page is parsed by the browser.

Here is the client.html :

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Socket.io</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Communicating with socket .io!</h1>

    <div>
        <form>
            <input id="wawa" type="text" name="firstname" value="">
            <button onclick="get_data()">Send data to server</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="socket-io.js"></script>

    <script>
        let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

        function get_data() {
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                console.log('Connected to the server');
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

server.js if it might help ?

```
let io = require('socket.io').listen(process.env.port||5000);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('New client connected');

    socket.on('wawa',function (data) {
        console.log(`data received is '${data}'`);
    });
```

Basically , I do not was the JS script to load when the page is parsed but to load only when a button is clicked.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you JavaScript area on the HTML file you can do this:

```
<script>
    var socket;

    function loadSocket() {
        socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
    }

    function get_data() {
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('Connected to the server');
        });
    }
</script>
```

In your HTML code you can have a button to call the loadSocket:

```
<button onclick="loadSocket();">Connect</button>
```

Comment: The variable socket remains empty, but accessible in the outer scope, when you click you add the right value to it.

Comment: is there a way to achieve this with require.js ?

Comment: I really don't know, never user Require.js.